# How do I auto increase a number in increments of one using an IF statement?

Tags: php

I am trying to echo a variable number, but I am not sure the best way to go about it. My problem is this:

I have a series of 'IF' conditions and I echo a variable accordingly.

```
   if ($month == "8" || $month == "9" || $month == "10") {
    $comingseason   = 'winter';
    $elementsDue    = "Due October 31, " . $year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. 9";
}
else if ($month == "11" || $month == "12" || $month == "1") {
    $comingseason   = 'spring';
    $elementsDue    = "Due January 31, " . ++$year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. 9";
}
else if ($month == "2" || $month == "3" || $month == "4") {
    $comingseason   = 'summer';
    $elementsDue    = "Due April 30, " . $year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. 9";
}
else if ($month == "5" || $month == "6" || $month == "7") {
    $comingseason   = 'fall';
    $elementsDue    = "Due July 31, " . ++$year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. 9";
}
```

I am wondering how I would replace the number in 'issue No. 9' with the next increment ++1 to output '10'? I don't want to have to come back into the code each time and type in the next issue number. I would like the number to increase on its own, essentially every quarter like you see below.

I was thinking of a php session, but from what I understand that will not be permanent. I need the number to remain even after a user has ended their session.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Starting at 'else if month 11 12 or 1' the number should output 10, then for month 2 3 and 4 the number would be 11 and then for month 5 6 and 7 the number would be 12, and the number would be 13 starting back at month 8 9 or 10.

Comment: http://codepad.org/2LBqMHCd  Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

may be you're looking for this,

Explanation: add an integer variable say it is $issuNo, and than add a initial value of that. Then after if/else condition block put the incremental var of that like $issuNo++ and then you better make a program that can continue your if/else statement later.

```
$issuNo = 9;     
if ($month == "8" || $month == "9" || $month == "10") {
        $comingseason   = 'winter';
        $elementsDue    = "Due October 31, " . $year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. ".$issuNo;
    }
    else if ($month == "11" || $month == "12" || $month == "1") {
        $comingseason   = 'spring';
        $elementsDue    = "Due January 31, " . ++$year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. ".$issuNo;
    }
    else if ($month == "2" || $month == "3" || $month == "4") {
        $comingseason   = 'summer';
        $elementsDue    = "Due April 30, " . $year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. ".$issuNo;
    }
    else if ($month == "5" || $month == "6" || $month == "7") {
        $comingseason   = 'fall';
        $elementsDue    = "Due July 31, " . ++$year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. ".$issuNo;
    }
$issuNo++;
```

Comment: Please explain your change in a few words.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this seems to be a very simple problem to solve. I would suggest reading a good entry level PHP programming book. Having said that, you need to set a `while` loop and some nested `if else` conditions.

```
$month = 0;

while ($month < 12) {
    $month++;

    If ($month > 7 && $month < 11)
    { 
        $comingsoon = "winter";
    }
    elseif 
    {
        some logic
    }
    elseif
    {
        some logic
    }
    else
    {

    }
} # end of while loop
```

I am intentionally leaving the remaining code for you to write.  It would be a good exercise for you to learn some coding :)  Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the issue # is a function of year and quarter: you have 1 issue per quarter starting at some base year/quarter.  So, something like this should automatically calculate it (you'll have to play with $base_year and $base_qtr to get it to match your issue numbering).

```
function currentIssue() {
    $base_year = 2014;
    $base_qtr = 2;
    $now_year = intval(date('Y');
    $now_qtr = ceil(intval(date'm')/3);
    return ($now_year - $base_year)*4 + ($now_qtr - $base_qtr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you're looking for:

```
<?php

$month = '3';
$year = '2015';
$issue = 9;
 if ($month == "8" || $month == "9" || $month == "10") {
    $comingseason   = 'winter';
 echo   $elementsDue    = "Due October 31, " . $year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. $issue";
}
else if ($month == "11" || $month == "12" || $month == "1") {
    $comingseason   = 'spring';
        $issue = $issue + 1;

echo    $elementsDue    = "Due January 31, " . ++$year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. $issue";
}
else if ($month == "2" || $month == "3" || $month == "4") {
    $comingseason   = 'summer';
        $issue = $issue + 2;
echo    $elementsDue    = "Due April 30, " . $year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. $issue";
}
else if ($month == "5" || $month == "6" || $month == "7") {
    $comingseason   = 'fall';
    $issue = $issue + 3;
echo    $elementsDue    = "Due July 31, " . ++$year . ", for our " . $comingseason . " issue No. $issue";
}
?>
```

[PHP fiddle](http://codepad.org/2LBqMHCd)

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. I've tested it a couple of different ways, and once you get past the last else if statement and we go back to the top to month 8 9 or 10, we're back at issue no. 9 instead of going on to 13. I understand because $issue = 9 in the first place, but how do we get the number to continue upwards?

Comment: @Marlon So you want it to be non-static? i.e. Showing only the specific `$issue` every time?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to show the specific issue. How you wrote your code is fine, it's just that once the end is reached the numbers repeat and don't continue to increase.

Comment: @Marlon they are suppose to repeat since that's the end of the `if-statement` do you have more of the `if-statements`?

Comment: No, that is all of the if statements. Sounds like those statements would have to go on forever in order to accomplish what i am trying to accomplish this specific way?

Comment: @Marlon the way I understood it, you had to show specific `$issue` for a particular `if-statement` and this will get the job done. The next time you run it, it won't have the previous value since its non-static.

Comment: Is there a way to do this outside of an IF statement?

Comment: @Marlon Ofcourse there could be, if you can explain better what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Each quarter a number is needed. In this case we need no. 9 which exists out there hard coded in as 'no. 9.' The next number should auto populate as 10, and then 11, 12 etc. It does not have to be in an IF statement. I think a variable would work in some way. The number just needs to constantly count up. Since we are seeking no. 9 currently, we would need to start there, as opposed to '0.'